# Counting $(0,1)$ matrices with 3 one's in each row and column

Tags: combinatorics

If $f(n)$ is the number of $n\times n$ binary matrices with exactly three $1$'s in all rows and all columns, then $f(n) = 6^{-n}n!^2 \displaystyle\sum_{\alpha+\beta+\gamma=n}\dfrac{(-1)^\beta(\beta+3\gamma)!2^\alpha3^\beta}{\alpha!\beta!\gamma!^2 6^\gamma}$ where the sum ranges over $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \geq 0$

This is from the introductory chapter of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Vol1. How does one arrive at this summation?

Comment: What have you attempted yet ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Not much more than taking specific $n$'s and counting! Cant seem to figure out how to use a generating function (recursively or other) either

Comment: The number of $n\times n$ binary matrices with exactly **two** $1$s in each row and column is [OEIS A001499](http://oeis.org/A001499); some of the references there may be helpful.

Comment: Connected : an article by Henderson and Dean  https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82325344.pdf